# Saving VC on exit (IOS)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have the code to **save VC** on **exit**.

It works but I use **SWRevealViewController** but the **navigation controller** in the application is not displayed

How can I correct it?

**ViewController.swift**

```
super.viewDidLoad()
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(0, forKey: "View")
```

**ViewController2.swift**

```
super.viewDidLoad()
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(1, forKey: "View")
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
let viewCount = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "View")
var VC = UIViewController()
let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
print(viewCount)
if viewCount == 0 {
    VC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "First") as! ViewController
} else if viewCount == 1 {
    VC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Second") as! ViewController2
}

self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
self.window?.rootViewController = VC

return true
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQ56U.jpg)

[My StoryBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlR7p.png)

Comment: Please clarify this sentence: "It works but I use SWRevealViewController but the navigation controller in the application is not displayed" I don't understand what you are even trying to say

Comment: @JonasSchafft I tested this code without (SWRevealViewController) and with (SWRevealViewController) and the navigation controller is not displayed

Comment: What I understand by your sentence "navigation controller in the application is not displayed" is that you want to grab the navigation controller? right?

Comment: Also can you please paste your storyboard image? it will show the clear picture. And confirm that does your views are embedded in UINavigationController?

Comment: @NSIceCode Yes, right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think the issue is that you are setting the root view controller of the window to be a regular view controller. What you need to do is set this to be a navigation controller with your embedded view controllers. I'm not sure of your exact setup with `SWRevealViewController` but I guess you need something like this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let viewCount = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "View")
    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let VC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "First") as! ViewController
    let frontNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC)
    let VC2 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TableView") as! TableView
    let rearNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC2)
    let revealVC = SWRevealViewController(rearViewController: rearNavigationController, frontViewController: frontNavigationController)
    revealVC.delegate = self
    self.window?.rootViewController = nil
    self.window?.rootViewController = revealVC
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

If this isn't working, or what you are looking to achieve, please ask in comments.

EDIT:

So, if you want to display the `TableView` menu on the left, you have to set the storyboard id of it to be `TableView` (obvs set this in the storyboard). And then the code above should work.

I'm not entirely sure why you are using `UserDefaults` to save the VC. But you can now use the `TableView` class to navigate between VCs. If you want to save the last visited VC and display this on application finished launching, you would need this:

```
var string = ""
switch viewCount {
case 0:
  string = "First"
case 1:
  string = "Second"
case 2:
  string = "Third"
case 3:
  string = "Fourth"
case 4:
  string = "Fifth"
default:
  string = "First"
}
let VC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: string)
let frontNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC)
```

Just make sure you have set the storyboard id of each VC to be "First", "Second", "Third" and so on. This would replace the previous declarations of `let VC` and `let frontNavigationController` in my above answer.

Comment: Error: Argument labels '(withRearViewController:, frontViewController:)' do not match any available overloads

Comment: when I use this code it turns out that that is shown on a photo "Error"

Comment: so the navigation bar is still not visible? please clarify

Comment: NavigationController is visible but the menu on the right displays another VC

Comment: Crashes on "revealVC? .delegate = self as! SWRevealViewControllerDelegate" - 'Thread 1: signal SIGABRT'

Comment: you need to add the following line to app delegate declaration: `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, SWRevealViewControllerDelegate {`

Comment: Anyway in the menu place with the left shows another VC

Comment: and for the other issue, can you please explain which view controller you want displayed in the menu?

Comment: You probably need to create a table view controller separate to view controller 1 and 2 which you specify in the question and implement delegate methods to navigate to these view controllers on cell selection. This view controller then needs to be set as the rear view controller of the `SWRevealViewController`.

Comment: Left - TableView

Comment: So is ViewController1 the table view or ViewController2 the table view?

Comment: Watch my storyboard in question

Comment: I still don't know what class your table view menu is!

Comment: TableView.swift is connected to my table

Answer (score 0):

If in your storyboard your initial ViewController is UINavigationViewController then you can access this navigation controller in AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` as follows:

```
let navigationController = application.windows[0].rootViewController as! UINavigationController
```

Also, there is no need to track/save your view controllers in UserDefaults, you can always access the list of ViewControllers like this

**AppDelegate**

```
let childViewControllers = window?.rootViewController?.childViewControllers
print("childVC: \(String(describing: childViewControllers))")
```

In Any other **ViewController**

```
let childViewControllers = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.childViewControllers
print("vcs : \(String(describing: childViewControllers))")
```

And of course, you can compare childViewControllers list

```
if let childViewControllers = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.childViewControllers {
    for viewController in childViewControllers {
        if viewController is FirstViewController {
            print("firstViewController found...")
        }
        if viewController is SecondViewController {
            print("secondViewController found...")
        }
    }
}
```

In case if you're setting SWRevealViewController for side-menu using storyboard then the basic setup should be like
[image]

For more detail on **SWRevealViewController** have a look at their GitHub [documentation](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController), check sample project and mentioned tutorials here for deep understanding. Hope it helps.

Comment: an error appears in the "let navigationController = application.windows[0].rootViewController as! UINavigationController" - 'Thread 1: signal SIGABRT'

Comment: Try this:

`if let navigationController = UIApplication.shared.windows[0].rootViewController {
            if navigationController is UINavigationController {
                print("Yes it is navigationController")
            }
        }`

Comment: Where you want to insert ''if let childViewControllers = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow? .rootViewController? .childViewControllers ...'' ???